# Systrace output not showing graphics/surfaceflinger events

Tags: android, systrace, surfaceflinger

I am able to run systrace but i am not able to see the traces for SurfaceFlinger. GPU, bufferQueues, etc.

I gave the following command:
systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html sched gfx view wm hal video workq

Its only giving output for CPU0, workqueues, irqs, kworker etc.

Any particular tracers we have to enable while compiling kernel? Am I missing anything else?

Thank You!

Comment: I tried to see the atrace output. In Atrace output itself i am not able to see any surfaceflinger or userspace level events. Seems like i am missing on enabling something. Anu pointers?

Comment: SurfaceFlinger and buffer queues are logged from user space and don't require any unusual steps to enable. I assume you're running as root since you've got the kernel stuff showing up. What version of Android? Is the device actively updating the display while systrace is capturing data?

Comment: we are using kitkat 4.4 on arm processor. We are running a video while capturing the systrace output.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution. 
The trace_marker file was not set to writeable for user space processes. After setting it using 
chmod 222 /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker   and doing 
adb shell stop 
adb shell start
It started working.